# SQL Server 2008 Setup Error 0x80070490

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, installation

I am trying to install SQL Server 2008 x64 on Windows 2008 R2 and keep getting the following error:

> *SQL Server Setup has encountered the following error: Element not
>   found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070490)*

I have applied all required patches and there are no other instances of SQL Server on the machine.

Any clues as to what the cause might be?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The error is caused if there is offline and removed disks inside the cluster (that are no longer presented to the server nodes). Removing the disks and re-running the installer fixed the problem.